# Liferay add multiple portlet in tab

Tags: tabs, liferay-6, jsf-2.2

I am very much new in Liferay 6.2 EE Portal development, I'm developing portal where I need to display TAB on some pages and each tab has multiple portlet (Like page layout, I can add dynamic portlet in TAB). 
Friends, I'm struggling from last one week and yet to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a navigation portlet, style it as tabs and create child pages to display the portlets in.

Comment: Hi Micheal, Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me know how to create navigation portlet?